# MySQL - Update a record and maintain referential integrity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working in MySQL 5.5.

I've got a Contacts table like this

`CREATE TABLE Contacts
    (
        ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        Institution VARCHAR(255),
        Address VARCHAR(255),
        Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        Phone VARCHAR(10)
    );`

and an Inventories tables like this

`CREATE TABLE Inventories
    (
        ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        InventoryParametersID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        ContactID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        LocationID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        Year INTEGER,
        DateUploaded TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        Comments VARCHAR(255),
        FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES Contacts(ID)
    );`

In my webform, contacts upload inventories. Here's the behavior I want:
- When a new contact uploads an inventory, do an insert with their new info
- When an existing contact (determined by email address) uploads another inventory, update their info AND retain referential integrity with the Inventories table

How do I do this?

Here's what I've tried:

CASE

```
FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES Contacts(ID)

REPLACE INTO Contacts (`Name`, `Institution`, `Address`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

RESULT

```
No change
```

CASE

```
FOREIGN KEY (ContactID) REFERENCES Contacts(ID)

    ON UPDATE CASCADE

REPLACE INTO Contacts (`Name`, `Institution`, `Address`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

RESULT

```
No change
```

Comment: A REPLACE deletes find row and add a new. So your ON UPDATE CASCADE doesn't work. Why do you not use an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: That's what I'm working on now, but I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax. Have you got a link to a good example other than the MySQL docs?

Comment: INSERT INTO Contacts (`Name`, `Institution`, `Address`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Name = VALUES(NAME), Institution = VALUES(Institution) ...

[MySQL-DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I got it:
INSERT INTO Contacts (`Name`, `Institution`, `Address`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Name`=?, `Institution`=?, `Address`=?, `Phone`=?;

Comment: You can use VALUES(`columnname`) in your updates, then you haven't set the values if you use a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REPLACE deletes find row and add a new. So your ON UPDATE CASCADE doesn't work. Why do you not use an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

```
INSERT INTO Contacts (Name, Institution, Address, Email, Phone) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
Name = VALUES(NAME), 
Institution = VALUES(Institution) ...
```

[MySQL DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)